# How to Send Ctrl+Shift+F1 to an application using send keys

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination of keys to an application.

But when I try to send the keys i am getting an error,the error is, `^+F1` is not a valid key.

The code I am using is:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{^+F1}");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) you need to have your braces around just the F1. Try this to see if it works

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^+{F1}");
```

From above link by enclosing the ^ and + in the braces you are sending the literal character.

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({})

**added by barlop - explanatory note-**

(from the documentation link above)

```
SHIFT +
CTRL ^
ALT %
```

and

```
F1 {F1}
F2 {F2}
```

Comment: is it possible to press alt+ctrl+delete from sendkey??

Comment: YES... JUST USE THIS   ^%{DEL}