# Send keys SHIFT + CTRL + S is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I need to save a PDF [image]file which is being opened at Webpage (Integrated Adbobe reader on the webpage). To save the  PDF I need to programmatically press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

I'm using:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+^(s)");
```

I also tried these combinations. None of them are working:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("+^(s)");
SendKeys.SendWait("^+s");
```

However, if I pass (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) for printing:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^(p)")
```

I'm not sure why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is not working.

If I manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it is working. But in sendkeys it doesn't work.

Comment: Got any solution for it? i also have same requirement

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^+{S}");`

More:
[How to Send Ctrl+Shift+F1 to an application using send keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557733/how-to-send-ctrlshiftf1-to-an-application-using-send-keys)

Comment: Thanks. I did try this. But the window is not popping up. If I manually press SHIFT + CTRL + S  it is popping up

Comment: Try changing to a lowercase s: `Send("^+{s}")`. I've noticed for example that `Send("^{S}")` will actually send Ctrl + Shift + S, so a similar problem could be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Windows Input Simulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) .NET wrapper for the Win32 [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) API. It gives you more direct control over the use of shift and control keys.

Comment: Do We know why the send keys for  SHIFT + CTRL + S is not working? on other hand I could see send keys for CTRL + P is working.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using Input Simulator though no luck. below is the code I have used. Please correct me if Im wrong.                        //InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
                        //InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);
                        //InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);

Comment: My guess is that it's using GetAsyncKeyState() to read the shift key state, in which sending keys won't work (e.g. read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890972/simulating-key-press-with-postmessage-only-works-in-some-applications)). Do other CTRL+X commands work while all SHIFT+CTRL+X commands don't?

Comment: I'm not sure. However CTRL + P is working with Simulator... InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL,  VirtualKeyCode.VK_P); On other Hand this is not working

Comment: Try this: InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL); then the VK_S, then wait a bit and then the KeyUps for shift and control.

Comment: I did try though no Luck. I could see the Shift key is being pressed. I checked using Iskeypressdown check. Not sure why save window is not popping up.

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys.Send("^+S");
This should work

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to make the window visible and activate it before sending the keys. For whatever reason, that let me send ctrl shift s. Only using activate did not work.

So something like this, where "i" is my window that was looped to find:

```
shellObj.Windows(i).Visible = True
AppActivate shellObj.Windows(i).LocationName
SendKeys "^+{S}", True
```