# How to simulate keypress (alt plus C)

Tags: c#, keypress

I need an `.exe` file that will simulate holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and key <kbd>C</kbd>.

I would use that `.exe` for another project.

How can I simulate this key combination with C#?

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%c");
```

Where `%` simulates pressing `Alt` and `c` simulates pressing `C`

See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557733/how-to-send-ctrlshiftf1-to-an-application-using-send-keys) and [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=vs.110).aspx) for more

You can also check [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) for more options